# Is earning money through Bitcoin and crypto currency mining halal?

Tags: halal-haram, finance

Is earning money through crypto currency mining haram because most of my family members think it is interest and it is like earning money without doing work.

Comment: There are many bitcoin questions on the site i wonder if this really is something new!

Comment: @Medi1Saif None of those many question answer "Is earning through Mining Halal?" i.e. I am selling computer power and getting paid in USD (not using or holding Bitcoin/Altcoin)